C# Winform app - Data Access library method errors on DatabaseProviderFactory().Create("Dataconnectionstring")
I am working with an existing N-Tier designed project, models, business layer, data access and a common library. The solution contains also 2 .NET web applications and I've added a new winform project/application. I've referenced the business layer library and common library in the winform project, added NUGET package system.data.sqlclient and an app.config file with the DB connection string, however when I'm accessing the data access layer method with the winform app. I receive error 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'The connection string for the database 'connectionstring' does not exist or does not have a valid provider.' 'ConfigurationErrorsException: The requested database connectionstring does not have a valid ADO.NET provider name set in the connection string. '
Below is my app.config code in the winform app:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstring" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=XYZXYZXYZXYZ;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserId;Password=PASSWORD" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Data access method:
DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory(), false);
Database db = new DatabaseProviderFactory().Create("connectionstring"); "ERRORS HERE"
string sqlCommand = "USP_TEST";

I've googled it and no luck, all or most tell me to add the providerName which is there in the app.config file. In addition, I've also modified the file property to 'copy always', no luck.
The web applications have the same connection string in the web.config file and the data access method picks up the connection string with no issues.
Not sure what I'm missing, any help is much appreciated.
Thank you, William
